# Initiate a Docusign Request

Tags: docusignapi

I'm fairly new to Docusign and have a fairly basic question.

Assume I have my Integrator Key, etc. already set up.

A user will select a file in my application and then select "Send for signature," and all my application will do is initiate the esignature process and send the file to Docusign.  My application won't know whose Docusign account it is or who the recipient(s) will be.

Then a new window (or an iframe) will appear, hosted by Docusign, where the user will be asked to enter their Docusign username and password (or to register if they don't have an account), and then the user will complete the rest of the process (identify the signature block, indicate who needs to sign, etc.)

This is similar to how Box.com integrates with Docusign.  Most of the API calls I have seen request the recipient's information.  All I will have is the file itself, and the information that identifies my application making the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a very generic question on how to build a workflow.

If you're only sending a few different documents to random recipients, then PowerForms sounds like it'd fit your need and it doesn't require programming (it's a DocuSign Premium Feature).

If you want to build out your own Integration, then the functionality can expand to whatever your needs may be.

---

### DocuSign Developers Center

To get information on where to start with your own integration, I'd start in the [DocuSign Developers Center](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center). From there you can click on [First API Call](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/first-api-call) and see how to make API calls with your integrator key.

There is also examples on the [API Walkthroughs Page](http://iodocs.docusign.com/apiwalkthroughs) on how to send a document for signature via the API in a variety of sample languages.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to use the examples to obtain what I need.  All of the examples include logging into Docusign.  But I do not want to log in toe Docusign. Instead, the end user will log themselves in manually. (I also don't want to include any other information, like recipients.) I just want to send over the document(s) and start a session and let the end  user handle the rest.

Comment: The workflow that you're referencing still uses Box Integration credentials to communicate with DocuSign. They have the user log into their DocuSign account to send the information, but they're the one's still doing all of the authentication management and sending it to DocuSign. It sounds like you need to design a workflow, I suggest contacting your Account Manager at DocuSign. They have Professional Services that are directed towards those getting started with a brand new workflow.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, we would be using our own integration credentials to communicate with Docusign, but have the user login.